# Referencing JSTL variable across multiple tags

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to encapsulate portions of a loop into smaller tags in JSTL. So I have a c:forEach and inside each, I  some variable names and can refer to them later inside the tag.

I want to then break out a smaller part of the for loop into a different tag (or anything else) to reuse it, for example the same code is being used in a different tag, and want to reuse the same tag across both files.

When I refer to the variable from the outer tag in the inner tag, it's undefined/blank, or potentially stale, like referring to some old version of the variable I set it equal to. IntelliJ also recognizes that it will be empty but doesn't seem to help.

I've tried messing around with the scope for the  but it doesn't seem to be helping. I've also tried  at the end of the loop to try to clear the variables. Can anyone help me understand here?

Comment: Some example code (or pseudo-code) would help to better understand your question.